# Imprimir datos en una impresora desde python en windows

Tags: python, windows

Estoy investigando un poco la forma de imprimir datos en una impresora local desde Python en Windows.

Si tienes el documento y su ruta, una forma sencilla que encontré fue esta:

```
import os
os.startfile("C:/Users/Jdash/Desktop/TestFile.txt", "print")
```

Sin embargo, lo que quiero es enviar directamente la cadena de texto, sin tener que crear el documento.

Este código de [Windows Printing Via Python](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/pythonicwindowsprinting.html) parece lograr lo que quiero:

```
# create a dc (Device Context) object (actually a PyCDC)
dc = win32ui.CreateDC()

# convert the dc into a "printer dc"

# get default printer
printername = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter ()
# leave out the printername to get the default printer automatically
dc.CreatePrinterDC(printername)

# you need to set the map mode mainly so you know how
# to scale your output.  I do everything in points, so setting
# the map mode as "twips" works for me.
dc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS) # 1440 per inch

# here's that scaling I mentioned:
scale_factor = 20 # i.e. 20 twips to the point

# start the document.  the description variable is a string
# which will appear in the print queue to identify the job.
dc.StartDoc('Win32print test')

# to draw anything (other than text) you need a pen.
# the variables are pen style, pen width and pen color.
pen = win32ui.CreatePen(0, int(scale_factor), 0)

# SelectObject is used to apply a pen or font object to a dc.
dc.SelectObject(pen)

# how about a font?  Lucida Console 10 point.
# I'm unsure how to tell if this failed.
font = win32ui.CreateFont({
    "name": "Lucida Console",
    "height": int(scale_factor * 10),
    "weight": 400,
})

# again with the SelectObject call.
dc.SelectObject(font)

# okay, now let's print something.
# TextOut takes x, y, and text values.
# the map mode determines whether y increases in an
# upward or downward direction; in MM_TWIPS mode, it
# advances up, so negative numbers are required to
# go down the page.  If anyone knows why this is a
# "good idea" please email me; as far as I'm concerned
# it's garbage.
dc.TextOut(scale_factor * 72,
    -1 * scale_factor * 72,
    "Testing...")

# must not forget to tell Windows we're done.
dc.EndDoc()
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿qué otras formas existen para lograr imprimir desde Python en Windows que permita enviar la cadena de texto directamente?

¿O quizás me estoy complicando y la creación del documento pasa desapercibida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un forma de imprimir directo es utilizando `win32print`. [Aquí](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) hay varios ejemplos donde también muestra otras formas de imprimir texto, archivos pdf, imágenes etc., desde Python en Windows. Pero lo que buscas, al parecer, es lo siguiente:

```
import os, sys
import win32print

printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter ()

if sys.version_info >= (3,):
  raw_data = bytes ("This is a test", "utf-8")
else:
  raw_data = "This is a test"

hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter (printer_name)
try:
  hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter (hPrinter, 1, ("Test de datos en bruto", None, "RAW"))
  try:
    win32print.StartPagePrinter (hPrinter)
    win32print.WritePrinter (hPrinter, raw_data)
    win32print.EndPagePrinter (hPrinter)
  finally:
    win32print.EndDocPrinter (hPrinter)
finally:
  win32print.ClosePrinter (hPrinter)
```

Aqui otro ejemplo que al parecer es mas universal. Probado en dos impresoras distintas. (El de arriba solo funciono en una)

```
import win32ui
import win32print
import win32con

INCH = 1440

hDC = win32ui.CreateDC ()
hDC.CreatePrinterDC (win32print.GetDefaultPrinter ())
hDC.StartDoc ("Test doc")
hDC.StartPage ()
hDC.SetMapMode (win32con.MM_TWIPS)
hDC.DrawText ("TEST", (0, INCH * -1, INCH * 8, INCH * -2), win32con.DT_CENTER)
hDC.EndPage ()
hDC.EndDoc ()
```

[Referencia del código](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/pythonicwindowsprinting.html)

Comment: Alcanzaste a probar el código? porque no me esta funcionando por el momento. Revisaré mejor para ver si estoy haciendo algo mal. Ahora estoy probando en win10 por cierto...

Comment: Si, lo probe pero hice varias pruebas antes que me resultara. Lo importante es que si no te da error es por que funciona pero el problema puede estar en que la impresora no está seteada por omisión u otra cosa.  prueba haciendo un 'print printer_name' y te debería dar el nombre de tu impresora.

Comment: Excelente la opción 2 me esta funcionando. Podrías profundizar un poco sobre que es lo que esta haciendo el código y donde podría encontrar más información?